# Sorting Array of Datas in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, timestamp

Say I have Stored some array of data using NSMutableArray. The stored array contains Timestamp and real time datas

I am receiving array of size 6 each time from a sensor device. The first position always has time stamp data and remaining position is occupied by real time datas. So, I have stored them sequentially in an NSMutableArray 
[image]

Here I am receiving datas with Time stamp in different order. So, I am in need to sort the time stamp in Ascending order with respect to datas (array of size 5) that are tied up with time stamp. So that I can able to plot the graph associated with each time stamp.

So my question is how to sort the time stamp without disturbing the data that are associated with each TimeStamp values.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `-sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`

eg.

```
NSArray * sortedArray = [otherArray sortedArrayUsingFunction: DataComparatorF context:nil];

NSInteger DataComparatorF (id a, id b, void *context)
{
   // return NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedAcending or NSOrderedDecending of a with respect to b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different format for storing your data -- I would use an array of dictionaries with 2 keys, one for the timestamp, and one for the data (whose value would be an array of the 5 values). Then you can sort the array with sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:, using sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending: as the descriptor (and passing whatever key name you use for the timestamp). You don't say what form your timestamp is in. If it's a string, you'll probably have to convert it to an NSDate object first to sort it properly.